# How to correctly center website

Tags: web, center

im looking for center my website in the middle of the browser. This is my website:

http://marcosballester1.hol.es/test/test2.html

Left side is correctly centered, but right side no. Code:

```
<style>
#wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
<body>
   HOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLAHOLA</body>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your original and the first answer are working as expected. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4k5pp/3/)

I added a background-color property to show you hide wide your `div` is. The `div` is centered on the page, but the text is overflowing outside of the box, because it is one continuous word and your browser doesn't want to break up a single continuous word. If you had multiple words in that box such as `hello hello hello ...` that wouldn't be an issue, because they would automatically wrap.

If you want to force your text to wrap you can use the `word-wrap: break-word` property, as shown in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/4k5pp/2/).

Answer (score -1):

You have a error
you must put body **before** a **div**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto; //to center div
}

<div class="wrapper">
Hello
</div>
```